# Single Use Express Routes? (Or alternative Node.js HTTP server)

Tags: node.js, express, httpserver

**What I'd like to do is server single use addresses which only return the requested body data *one time*.**

After a single use I'd like the routes to "self-destruct" by becoming inaccessible, or returning a 404 error for that route.

Is there a way to do this with Express 4? If not, or if it's too involved, is there some other Node package that can solve this problem? Thanks very much!

Comment: Whats wrong with route params `/v1/resourse/:somepath` ? you can have your own logic to handle validation and dynamic routing, also an example of your use case would be great.

Comment: Yes, it's easily possible with Express using either the last path segment of the URL `/something/:code` that varies and contains a single use code or using a query parameter `/something?code=xxxx` with a `/something` route.  In both cases, you define one route that is specified for the common part of the URL and examines the one varying part of the URL to decide whether it's valid or not and what to do with it.